# Error in final launch sequence Failed for OpenOCD (Olimex) for ARM (STM32fxx)

Tags: microcontroller, arm, stm32, openocd, gdb

I am using openOCD in eclipse for the arm STM32F10x series. After writing the whole code and  building everything without error in the program, I am going to debug it and I am getting an error after completion of 99% of the process. The following error is generated and I am not able to debug my program.

```
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:  
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
Error creating process
```

Comment: Double post from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220944/error-in-final-launch-sequence-failed-for-openocd-olimex-for-arm-stm32fxx/15233950#15233950

Answer (score 1):

This is a gdb error (the "back-end here refers to the gdb backend, in opposition with the front-end which is integrated with Eclipse). You need to give more information about your configuration, from what you said you are using Eclipse with openOCD and GDB. Did you compile openOCD correctly for your target? Which operating system are you using?

It also seems that you are confused about openOCD, openOCD is a program which does the JTAG communication with your target (in your case through the "Olimex", I assume you mean the Jtag Key from Olimex?). Once OpenOCD is launched and function correctly you can use GDB to debug your target.

Answer (score 0):

OCD isn't a compiler, it's a backend for the GCC compiler.
You can send an e-mail to the [OpenOCD mailing list](http://openocd.sourceforge.net/discussion/mailing-lists/) that would have the best answers for the issue

Comment: GDB is also not a compiler ;-)

Comment: @EtienneCordonnier: Woops. Didn't notice I put that. I meant GCC :D